# Long to String before converting to a BigDecimal

Tags: java, java-8, type-conversion, long-integer, bigdecimal

I have to convert a Long (Object one, contained in the variable 'longValueToConvert') to a BigDecimal.

I would have done something like this :

```
new BigDecimal(longValueToConvert)
```

But i've read that this cast could induce errors in the conversion and that it is prefered to cast the Long to a String before using it to the BigDecimal constructor.

```
new BigDecimal(longValueToConvert.toString())
```

Is it Ok to use the first one or the second one would be preferable ? I use Java 8.

Comment: There is no cast involved in the code, and no, it doesn't cause any conversion error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You heard wrong. There is no conversion error from the [`BigDecimal(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-long-) constructor. A `long` can be represented exactly and there is no problem making a `BigDecimal` out of it.

You need to be careful only when you use the [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) constructor. This is because some `double` values can't be represented exactly. From the documentation:

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing `new BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to `0.1` [...], but it is actually equal to `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. This is because `0.1` cannot be represented exactly as a `double` [...].
>
> The `String` constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing `new BigDecimal("0.1")` creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to `0.1`, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this one.

Comment: Also, the [factory methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-long-int-) are preferable as they don't always create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
new BigDecimal(longValueToConvert.longValue())
```

This works fine. I believe your concern should be when representing floating point numbers as the precision matters there. e.g. when you are using `BigDecimal (double)` or `BigDecimal(float)` constructors. Do you have these scenarios? Also, the name here tells you everything. `Long` to any floating point number is not a problem, but the coming from the other directions requires care.

Comment: While this will work, the result will be exactly the same as `new BigDecimal(longValueToConvert)`

Comment: *"[Converting a] long to any floating point number is not a problem"* - Actually, converting a `long` to a `float` or a `double` *can* result in loss of precision.

Comment: Why convert a long to a long? Doesn't make lots of sense to me.